# Did Daniel Craig appear in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, actors, cameo

[Daniel Craig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Craig), noted for his film appearances as James Bond and his resemblance to Vladimir Putin, was rumoured to be *going to* appear in the new Star Wars film *The Force Awakens*. According to [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/jul/16/daniel-craig-on-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameo-rumours-id-never-bother) from the Guardian, Simon Pegg had a [Hagrid moment](http://e.lvme.me/tqnl5vl.jpg) when talking about cameos in TFA:

> I wasn’t a Stormtrooper. Daniel Craig, he was a Stormtrooper. ...I shouldn’t have said that.

But Craig himself denied the rumour with foul-mouthed gusto:

> Why would I ever bother doing something like that? Fucking hell! Pffft. Play an extra in another movie?

Now that TFA has been released, has this question been settled one way or the other?

**Did Daniel Craig appear in *The Force Awakens* or not?**

Comment: Define "appear"s.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [this article in *Entertainment Weekly* by Chris Lee](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/17/daniel-craig-makes-cameo-star-wars-force-awakens), the initial rumor was floating around since May 2015 and the author of that same piece confronted him earlier in the year during an interview about the rumor and Daniel Craig’s response was:

> “Why would I ever bother doing something like that?” Craig sputtered.
>   “F—ing hell! Pffft. Play an extra in another movie.”

But in the end, that [*Entertainment Weekly*](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/17/daniel-craig-makes-cameo-star-wars-force-awakens) article reveals that yes he did make a cameo in the film:

> So if Craig *had* wanted to make a cameo, it would have likely been as
>   simple as cozying up to *Star Wars* director J.J. Abrams, slipping out
>   of his Tom Ford suit and donning the white plastic helmet.
>
> According to multiple sources close to *The Force Awakens* who asked
>   not to be identified because they were not authorized to speak
>   publicly, that is precisely what happened.
>
> Craig *does* make a cameo in *Star Wars VII* as a stormtrooper,
>   turning up in one of the movie’s most memorably nostalgic scenes. “He
>   did it for sh–s and grins,” says one of the people with knowledge of
>   the actor’s performance.

And the scene he was in is described as…

> At one point in the movie, Daisy Ridley’s character Rey has been captured, and makes her maiden attempt at a Jedi mind trick.

> “You will remove these restraints and leave this cell with the door open,” Rey tells the stormtrooper, played by Craig.

> “I’ll tighten those restraints, scavenger scum,” Craig’s character responds, although few in the audience can be expected to register that it’s him. We only hear the actor’s clipped British diction and never see his face.

Further, on the [IMDB page for *The Force Awakens*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/fullcredits) he is listed as “Stormtrooper JB-007.”

Comment: Curious - is he listed in the credits as Storm Trooper #52?

Answer (score 15):

Addendum to the already given excellent answers. It appears to not only be Mr. Craig.
[Source](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/12/19/how-to-spot-all-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameos-from-daniel-craig-to-radiohead.html)  (*Note: The source contains spoilers*)

**Simon Pegg**

> ...it was well-known that SIMON PEGG had filmed a cameo in The Force Awakens for Abrams after starring for the director-producer’s Mission: Impossible and Star Trek reboots. Pegg can be seen and heard under layers of Crolute flesh as Unkar Plutt, the Jakku junk dealer who trades rations for spare parts and sends a few thugs to steal BB-8 from Daisy Ridley’s Rey.

**Daniel Craig**

> Fans also have [Simon] Pegg to thank for first spilling the beans on The Force Awakens’ funniest guest appearance. “I wasn’t a stormtrooper. DANIEL CRAIG, he was a stormtrooper,” he blabbed in May, seemingly confirming rumors that Star Wars fan Craig would be cameoing in Episode VII.

**Alec Guinness, Ewan McGregor**

> The Obi-Wan line came courtesy of not one, but two Kenobis: ALEC GUINNESS, whose archival utterance of the word “afraid” was cleverly edited into Abrams’ dream delivery of the name ‘Rey,’ and his prequel counterpart EWAN MCGREGOR, who recorded the rest.
> “So when you hear Obi-Wan talk to Rey it is both Alec Guinness and Ewan McGregor doing the voice,” said Abrams.

**Ken Leung**

> Here he’s Admiral Statura, a member of the rebel force set on taking down the First Order.

**Greg Grunberg**

> In The Force Awakens, he gets to live a geek dream as Snap Wexley, a Resistance fighter from a piloting family who’s part of Poe Dameron’s Starkiller Base attack squad.

**Yayan Runian, Iko Ywais, Cecep A. Rahman**

> YAYAN RUHIAN—aka Mad Dog from The Raid—gets to taunt Solo as Kanjaklub leader Tasu Leech, while IKO UWAIS sports some otherworldly coiffure as the whimsically-named Razoo Quin-Fee. The pair served double duty on The Force Awakens as credited fight choreographers on said Millennium Falcon sequence, which also boasts Raid 2 standout CECEP A. RAHMAN.

**Harriet Walter**

> Dowager Lady Shackleton of Downton Abbey tending to Chewbacca and his ego as Dr. Kalonia—or as the stage and screen veteran is known IRL, DAME HARRIET WALTER. (Fun fact: Walter is also the niece of another Star Wars icon, Sir Christopher Lee—Count Dooku himself.)

**Billie Lourd**

> ... cameos from British stars and Star Wars fam, including Carrie Fisher’s own daughter, BILLIE LOURD. The young actress shares the screen with her mother a few times at Resistance headquarters playing Lieutenant Connix, an officer in Leia’s new rebel army.

**Gerry Abrams**

> Abrams also cast his own dad, Emmy nominated producer GERRY ABRAMS, as a character named Count Cypress—and named Oscar Isaac’s X-wing pilot after his onetime personal assistant, Morgan Dameron, whose Star Wars name is, appropriately enough, Commodore Meta.

**Bill Hader, Ben Schwartz**

> Meanwhile, those adorable bleeps and blurps coming out of BB-8? They come courtesy of Saturday Night Live’s BILL HADER and BEN SCHWARTZ

**Thomas Brodie-Sangster, Jessica Henwick, Miltos Yerolemou, mark Stanley, Max Von Sydow**

> Over on the Dark Side, the fascist-like First Order is populated with sinister-sounding Brits. The Maze Runner’s THOMAS BRODIE-SANGSTER turns in a one-liner as an officer of the First Order, one of several Game of Thrones stars to pop up in The Force Awakens alongside Gwendoline Christie’s Chrome Trooper Captain Phasma. (See also: JESSICA HENWICK, Season 5 and 6’s Nymeria Sand, who battles in an X-wing as one of the Resistance’s female pilots; MILTOS YEROLEMOU, who played GoT’s Syrio Forel and also gave Eddie Redmayne his sexual reassignment surgery this awards season in The Danish Girl; MARK STANLEY, who played Night’s Watch ranger Grenn but is hard to spot as an unnamed Kylo Ren disciple; and MAX VON SYDOW, who’s joining GoT as one of Season 6’s big name additions.)

**Michael Giacchino, Nigel Godrich, Gustavo Dudamel, Lin-Manuel Miranda**
**Tom Kane, Meredith Salenger, Catherine Taber, Sam Witwer, Matt Lanter, James Arnold Taber, and director Dave Filoni**

> And then there are the fun, random cameos that you’d never know existed otherwise. Longtime Abrams composer MICHAEL GIACCHINO dons a stormtrooper costume as a First Order soldier named FN-3181, while Radiohead recording producer NIGEL GODRICH plays stormtooper FN-9330.
>
> Abrams had even more musical surprises up his sleeve. The LA Philharmonic’s own dashing music director GUSTAVO DUDAMEL came in to guest-conduct portions of John Williams’ Force Awakens score in secrecy. And those cantina-esque ditties blaring in Maz Kanata’s space pirate bar come courtesy of Hamilton composer-star and expert freestyler LIN-MANUEL MIRANDA, who sang alongside Abrams in Huttese on jams titled “Jabba Flow” and “Dobra Doompa.”
>
> Meanwhile, The Force Awakens also played host to the voice cast of its popular animated prequel series Star Wars: The Clone Wars. Listen closely for the voice work of Clone Wars stars Tom Kane, Meredith Salenger (yes, Natty Gann herself), Catherine Taber, Sam Witwer, Matt Lanter, James Arnold Taber, and director Dave Filoni.

*Curtain Call*

> …it will make a gazillion bucks and be the highest-grossing movie of all time because it is a direct doorway to our childhood.”

Answer (score 3):

[The IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) claims that Craig had a minor role indeed. Also, according to [Io9](http://io9.gizmodo.com/oh-so-thats-who-daniel-craig-played-in-the-force-awake-1748678355),

> Craig plays the stormtrooper in the interrogation room scene.